# How do I produce XML with Perl's XML::Simple?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I am just trying to create the XML

```
use XML::Simple;

my %element = ( "a" => "10" , 
                "b" => "20" ,);

my $xs = new XML::Simple();
my $ref = $xs->XMLin(%element);
my $xml = $xs->XMLout($ref);
print $xml;
```

What is wrong on this code ?  ( This is got Resolved )

```
use XML::Simple;

my %element = ( "a" => "10" , 
                "b" => "20" ,);

my $xs = new XML::Simple();
my $xml = $xs->XMLout(\%element);
print $xml;
```

This produces the following output:

```
<opt a="10" b="20" />
```

But what I'd really like to get is this:

```
<a> 10 </a>
<b> 20 </b>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why did you make this community wiki? Why are you refusing to read the documentation?

Comment: by mistaken i made to community wiki .. How to rollback to..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMLin takes XML and transforms it into a Perl data structure.

XMLout takes a Perl data strcuture and transforms it to XML.

You are trying to feed a Perl data structure to XMLin and feed the result to XMLout.

Have you considered reading the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Simple)?

---

Update: The documentation (yes, we know it's boring) offers quite a lot of options that you can pass to `XML::Simple::new()`. One of them is `NoAttr => 1`. You might want to [check that one out](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Simple), but a look at the others (some of which are marked "important") won't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

You're using it backwards.  `XMLin` is an XML decoder (takes an XML-encoded document, returns Perl structures); `XMLout` is an XML encoder (takes Perl structures, returns an XML-encoded document).

Comment: Either way i am not able to acheive what i want . I just want to create the XML element based on Hash array